# Algorithm for finding connected components checking as few edges as possible

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs, connected

Is there a good algorithm to find connected components in undirected graphs with at the lowest possible costs given as the total weight of the edges being checked?

Comment: What do you mean "edges being checked"? I don't understand the problem statement.

Comment: By "checking an edge" I mean that there is a cost associated to knowing if the edge between two vertices actually exists.

Comment: Do we know all the costs in advance? Is it like "you can pay $c_{uv}$ to see whether $(u, v) \in E$"?
Also, how do you score solutions? What is the "lowest possible cost"? The lowest for which you can exhibit a proof certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) for each connected component.